# Nested collection view cells not resizing on orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

**Outer Collection View** *(In the file of ViewController)*

- Takes up entire width and height of the screen
- Cell also takes up entire width and height of the screen
- Collection View Layout is horizontal. Able to swipe to get to the next cell.
- Background of cell is green

**Nested Collection View** *(In the file of CollectionViewCell)*

- Takes up the entire width and height of the screen
- Cell takes up entire width of the screen. Height is 100,
- Background of cell purple.

**Problem**

1. I first run the app in portrait orientation on the simulator in Xcode.
2. When I change the orientation to landscape and swipe the all the screens,
3. One screen will have purple cells that don't take up the entire screen. This problem only occurs in landscape.

**The problem: always one screen that has purple cells like this**

[image: Screen Shot]

**How all cells are suppose to look on orientation landscape**

[image: Screen Shot]

4. If the problem did not occur change the orientation back to portrait, and then change it to landscape. Then swipe through all the cells again to find the problem.

**App Delagate**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        window = UIWindow()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        
        window?.rootViewController = ViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        
        return true
        
    }
    
}
```

**View Controller**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionView?.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellid")
        collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellid", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
    
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
    
}
```

**Collection View Cell** *(Has the Nested Collection View)*

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .green
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        backgroundColor = .purple
        
        addSubview(collectionView)
        
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        collectionView.register(InnerCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellid")
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellid", for: indexPath) as! InnerCell
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: frame.width, height: 100)
    }
    
}
```

**Inner Cell** *(Cell for the Nested Collection View)*

```
import UIKit

class InnerCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        backgroundColor = .purple
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

*I have the project on github* https://github.com/vk99x/Nested-Collection-View

Answer (score 2):

```
 override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    // Also try reloading your collection view to calculate the new constraints
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Hey check this and let's see if it helps